# what indexes to set for this query?

Tags: mysql, indexing

this query has a lot of different things:

- selects only certain columns
- Those columns are from different tables
- Has concat/count/case when
- joins
- Grouping

```
SELECT st.id AS stid,
    st.category,
    st.maxsubscriptions,
    CONCAT (
        st.category,
        ' (',
        COUNT(CASE 
                WHEN gs.id_subtournament = st.id
                    THEN 1
                ELSE NULL
                END),
        '/',
        st.maxsubscriptions,
        ')'
        ) AS ststring
FROM de_subtournaments AS st
LEFT JOIN de_gamers AS gs ON st.id = gs.id_subtournament
WHERE st.type = 0
    AND st.id_tournament = '6'
GROUP BY st.id
```

What should the index for this query look like and why?

Comment: If you are going to filter by it or join on it, then consider indexing it.

Comment: ok, so i should create one index for st.id, one for gs.id_subtournament, and one for st.type + st.id_tournament ? for a total of 3 indexes.. is that right?

Comment: An index on `st.id` won't be used.  When`JOINing`, _if you can figure out which table will be first_, the second table needs the index.  `LEFT` usually forces an order to the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the indexes I would suggest maintaining:

```
`de_subtournaments`: `id`, unless it's the primary key already with an index
`de_subtournaments`: `type` + `id_tournament`
`de_gamers`: `id_subtournament`, unless the foreign key already has an index
```

If you have other queries that need to run against `de_subtournaments` for `id_tournament` while not caring about `type`, consider creating also the following index (if it isn't already there for the foreign key):

```
`de_subtournaments`: `id_tournament`
```

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be a query-formulation question, more than an index question.

Note how you have a `JOIN` and a `GROUP BY`.  I call the the "inflate-deflate" pattern.  It can be costly.

The trick to speeding up such queries is to get rid of the `GROUP BY` and turn the `JOIN` into a subquery.

```
SELECT  st.id AS stid, st.category, st.maxsubscriptions,
CONCAT ( st.category,
         ' (', 
         IFNULL(
                ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
                      FROM  de_gamers
                      WHERE  id_subtournament = st.id ),
              0),
         '/',
         st.maxsubscriptions,
         ')' 
       ) AS ststring
    FROM  de_subtournaments AS st
    WHERE  st.type = 0
      AND  st.id_tournament = '6'
```

Now, to recheck the indexes:

```
st: INDEX(type, id_tournament)  -- in either order
de_gamers:  (id_subtournament)
```